# Wifi and Google Play access after factory reset for off contract Sprint HTC Evo 4G

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, google-account, factory-reset

I no longer use my old HTC Evo 4G I got from Sprint. I want to give it to my toddler so he can play games. Currently, since it is off contract it can't access the mobile network but it still can access WiFi.

If I do a factory reset on the phone will it still be able to have WiFi access? Will I still be able to access the Google Play store with my account?

Comment: Google services (Play Store, gmail, etc.) requires any kind of Internet access, cell or Wi-Fi. Your phone should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

A factory-reset deletes all the user data. It's as if you had a brand-new tablet (but any system updates you've previously installed will still be there).

This means the tablet won't have the password for connecting to your Wi-Fi network, nor the password for your Google account. The first time you turn it on, it will take you through the same initial setup process as when it was new: it'll prompt you to connect to a Wi-Fi network and log into a Google account. If you log in with the same Google account as before, it'll still be able to access all the apps (and books, music, films, etc.) you previously installed/bought from Google Play

Comment: Awesome. Just to make sure, you are saying that after the factory reset there no activation step that requires a connection to a mobile service provider?

Comment: It's not normally the case, but since carriers can customize the the initial setup process, if you originally got the phone from the carrier, it's possible that they did something like that to it. Only someone who's already tried it with the same device from the same carrier would be able to say for sure; you might want to update your question to say which carrier you got the phone from.